# Calculate the percent change between every rolling nth row in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, percentage

How can I calculate the percentage change between every rolling nth row in a Pandas DataFrame?  Using every 2nd row as an example:

Given the following Dataframe:

```
>df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[14, 4, 5, 4, 1, 55], 
               "B":[5, 2, 54, 3, 2, 32],  
               "C":[20, 20, 7, 21, 8, 5], 
               "D":[14, 3, 6, 2, 6, 4]})
```

I would like the resulting DataFrame to be:

[image]

But, the closest I am getting by using this code:

```
>df.iloc[::2,:].pct_change(-1)
```

Which results in this:

[image]

It is performing the calculation for every other row but this is not the same as the a rolling window of calculating every nth row.  I came across a similar Stack post but that example is not very straightforward.

Also, as a bonus, I'd like to display the resulting output as a percentage to two decimal places.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!  Use the option "periods" for 'pct_change()'.

```
>df.pct_change(periods=-n) #where n=2 for the given example.
```